# How is the human voice classified?

Tags: voice, sound, musicology

Considering the vocal cords can be a membranophone or considering the air column can be an aerophone.
or do we need another classification?

Comment: Interesting idea, but what's wrong with vox humana?

Comment: voice. the first instrument.

Comment: "vox humana" or "voice" would be that "other classification" I'm looking for, but is this correct? Is that how it is determined in books?. I'm considering the classification in idiophones, membranophones, chordophones, aerophone, electrophones

Comment: My comment was really meant to say I think there are times to dispense with academic thinking. Just my opinion. I'll add an answer to elaborate.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - many decades ago, at music college, a colleague was convinced that instruments were merely trying to imitate the human voice, but never got close. Still don't quite understand...  The other way round is more plausible. Make a sound like a trumpet, a flute, a drum...

Comment: @Tim. Not sure I understand you. Do you mean 10,000, 20,000 years ago human singing was trying to imitate a flute? That's sort of like a ancient cart being an imitation of an automobile. Surely the history and mimicking was the other way around. Percussion would be the other primal instrument. Of course this is just speculation with some common sense applied.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - no, I mean that it's possible for a human to imitate a trumpet, flute, drums...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is really an answer, but I thought I should elaborate on my comment which may have seemed glib or snarky.

The classification list is the [Mahillon and Hornbostel–Sachs system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_instrument_classification#Mahillon_and_Hornbostel%E2%80%93Sachs_systems) which I really didn't know about.

I'm not really sure about the logic of that system. It lumps together bells and maracas as *idiophones*, because the entire bodies of the instruments vibrate. I get the idea, but don't see any musical insight from it. Then again this system is 19th century "science" ...that's the same time period of *phrenology*. I think it's a little outdated.

Apparently there is a [Dewey Decimal-like classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hornbostel%E2%80%93Sachs) in that system. An aerophone has a vibrating air column, but the instrument itself doesn't vibrate (not sure that's true, especially brass) so that would not be the human voice as the vocal chord vibrate. Seems the voice is a "[242, Singing membrane, vessel kazoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hornbostel%E2%80%93Sachs#Tube_or_vessel-kazoos_(242))," because it's a vibrating membrane inside a container.

My original comment - "voice, the first instrument" - was meant say I think we should sometimes dispense with academic systems. Surely, the human voice was the first musical "instrument", the first means to express emotion with sound. I don't really care that it's like a kazoo. I care more about the voice's intrinsic qualities - the fact that it's easy for most people to make a distinct pitch, typical range of the voice, amplitude, and the limit of what can be sung in one breath. I think many musical fundamentals stem from what we can do with our *human* voices. IMO, it's more important to know the musical implications of our human voice limitations rather than classification as a vibrating kazoo-like membrane in a box.